# How to write a variable value in a file using ansible.builtin.template module?

Tags: ansible

I wanted to log content of a variable in a file. I did it like this,

```
 - name: write infraID to somefile.log
    copy:
      content: "{{ infraID.stdout }}"
      dest: somefile.log
```

And it worked. But in the documentation for `copy` [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/copy_module.html#parameter-content), I found that they have recommended to use `template` instead of `copy` in such cases.

> For advanced formatting or if `content` contains a variable, use the
> ansible.builtin.template module.

I went through the examples given at the documentation for template module [here](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html#examples). But I was unable to figure out something that works in my scenario. Could you please show me how to do this properly in recommended way ?
Thanks in advance !! Cheers!

Comment: It would good if you can post some details of "Some discrepancy", because it is not clear on what's your expectation, and what is the actual output.

Comment: The discrepancy is probably some sort of parse error: your example suffers from both malformed yaml and incorrect task definition. Moreover, please show what you have tried exactly and explain why it did not meet your requirements. Lastly, using `command` to launch `jq` to read an element from a json file, registering it in a var to get it back from `stdout` is a textbook case of ansible bad practice. You can read the file content inside a variable and use the value. Depending on your exact case, see modules `slurp` and `fetch`, the `file` lookup and the `from_json` filter

Comment: @seshadri_c The discrepancy I mentioned earlier was due to an error in metadata file itself. After fixing that it works as intended. But still I want to learn how write variables  using ```template``` instead of ```copy```. I'll edit my post accordingly. Thanks.

Comment: From the answer, you clearly see that the documentation saying "use template `if the content contains a variable`" is questionable. Your first solution using the `copy `module is simpler and does exactly the same what the `template` module does. Why would anybody want to write an extra file if it's possible to put the simple Jinja into the parameter?

Comment: @VladimirBotka -- "if the content contains a variable" refers to _data_ of the `content` value.  For instance, if `infraID.stdout` contained Jinja tags and the user wanted them interpolated with other vars (as if it were a template), then that's the scenario they're warning isn't supported.  If you don't intend to treat `content` as if it were a template, then the `copy` strategy is perfectly valid and IMO preferred.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `template` module does not have a `content` property.
You have to create a file that contains your template, for example:

**templates/infra-id-template**

```
{{ infraID.stdoud }}
```

**playbook**

```
---
- hosts: localhost

  tasks:
    - name: Get infra ID
      shell: echo "my-infra-id"
      register: infraID

    - name: Template the file
      template:
        src: infra-id-template
        dest: infra-id-file
```